# Blocking Vertical Spaces at the end of a String - Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm really struggling to get a simple regex to work. I know there are plenty of Q/A on that but I can't seem to find the proper solution.

I won't allow any special character, Vertical spaces in between (done by pressing enter) and vertical spaces at the end of the string, nothing more.

**Here is my Regex:**

`/^[^"#$%&\/:\v?\^_|£§°ÀÇÈÉÌÒÙ€]+$/`

It works as I want not allowing special characters and vertical spaces in between, but it won't work for vertical spaces at the very end of the string.

**I tried with:**

`/^[^"#$%&\/:\v?\^_|£§°ÀÇÈÉÌÒÙ€]+[^\v]$/`

But it won't work.

**How do I get this to work also for not allowing Vertical spaces at the very end of the string?**

I'm sorry If my problem is a bit Trivial.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You basically want to remove newlines. `string = string.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong. Instead of listing all forbidden characters, list all allowed characters. Start with something like:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/
```

and add eventual other characters you need.

Note: the shorthand character class `\v` doesn't exist in Javascript.

Comment: It works except the fact that it still accepts a single final vertical space. If I put 2 of them then the string won't be accepted.

Comment: @AndreaM16: It's because your are testing the pattern in regex tester designed for pcre (PHP) where the anchor `$` can match the end of the string or the end of the last line followed by a newline character. But it isn't the case with Javascript. Test it with a real code.

Comment: @AndreaM16: note that you can obtain the same default behavior with pcre using the D modifier.

Comment: Hi, the customer wants us to allow every character except the following: `# $ % & / : ? \ ^ _ | ¢ § ° À Ç È É Ì Ò Ù €  * VerticalSpace`. So far I tried `^[^#$%&/:?\^_|¢§°ÀÇÈÉÌÒÙ€*\v]+$` and it works except, again, on disallowing vertical spaces. Have you any idea on how can I fix this? I know it would have been more intelligent to follow your approach but, you know how customers think.

Comment: As I explained previously, the pattern doesn't allow vertical spaces already and the shorthand character class `\v` doesn't exist in Javascript. After, the definitive list of characters is no more a programming problem but a communication and a pedagogic problem with the customer. You should ask him and find why he wants to exclude this specific list of characters (what is the idea behind? Why `ÀÇÈÉÌÒÙ` and not `Ê`? Why `:` and not `;`?...).